# I'm not sure how to appropriately extend classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using some pre-built code in asp.net. It provides me with a `MembershipUser` class and also has several other classes that use `MembershipUser`.

I want to add a new property to `MembershipUser` without changing anything else. I still want all the pre-made functions to work with it.

How can I extend `MembershipUser` to include a new property without creating a separate class that the other functions have no knowledge of?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Could you create a profile property instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C# you only have three options for extending classes:

1. [Inheretance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [Decoration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx#S3))
3. [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Sadly, none of them will do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: for link 1,2, could you direct to some msdn links just as 3? wiki link is less specific.

Comment: "#2 is a design pattern", there must be some C# examples?

Comment: What about extending the type using a `partial` class?

Answer (score 1):

If you can inherit from the class, do that. For example if your property is a `string`

```
public class ExtendedMembershipUser : MembershipUser
{
    public string MyNewProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Or add an extension method if you can't inherit (you can't add a property):

```
public static class MembershipUserExtensions
{
    public static string MyNewMethod(this MembershipUser user)
    {
        return "answer";
    }
}
```